# Efficient containment checks in small collections

Tags: java, performance, collections, contains

Preamble: I know the basic difference beween containment checks in Lists and Sets.

For small collections of 2..50 elements is there a threshold where `ArrayList#contains(Object o)` is usually faster than `HashSet#contains(Object o)`? Since `HashSet#contains(Object o)` has more indirections I would expect such a threshold exists.

Side notes:

- Let's assume that the computational effort of `equals()` and `hashCode()` is somewhat comparable to the String implementation.
- The candiates `Object o` are typically new Objects and won't profit from fast equality checks of the kind `o1==o2`.

Comment: Why don't you make a benchmark for *your* specific case? Or are you going to trust some third-party speculations more than your own experiments in your particular environment?

Comment: OK, if we speculate about some abstract "small collection" of some abstract objects "somewhat comparable to the String", then ArrayList is almost always a bad choice for performing an object lookup on a performance critical path, regardless of the list size.

Comment: @apangin: I was hoping for some more general empirical figures. For instance, `Arrays#sort()` contains some empirical thresholds to choose the "somewhat optimal" sorting algorithm depending on the array's size: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java

Comment: This surely depends on the actual element type and likely will change, depending on optimization state (interpreted, tier 1 compiled, tier 2 compiled, etc) of the code in question. Given that the hash lookup takes a basically fixed time *t* and any saving can never be bigger than that small value of *t*, it’s not really worth wasting development effort on this.